# Geometrical argument to prove unboundedness

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

Is the following Proof Correct?

Let $a_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ prove $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

*Proof.* Let us demonstrate that $\{a_n\}$ has no upper-bound. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and consider the integer $C=(\frac{\lceil\epsilon\rceil+1}{2})^2$, geometrically it is not difficult to see that $a_n$ can be over-approximated using the integral under the curve $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ with $a_n$ representing a Riemann sum with $\Delta x =1$ and $r=0$ consequently
$$\forall n\ge 1\left(a_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{r+j\Delta x}}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}>\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{n}-1\right)$$
substituting for $n$ we see that 
$$a_n>2\sqrt{C}-1=2\sqrt{\left(\frac{\lceil\epsilon\rceil+1}{2}\right)^2}-1=\epsilon$$
since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary it follows that the sequence can be made arbitrarily large and is therefore unbounded.

Comment: Yep seems valid, although I don't think you would need to include a Riemann sum in there. In general, for a monotonically decreasing function, [the integral of the function being summed is less than the sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). Integrating $x^s$ between $[1,\infty]$ for $s\le1$ results in a divergent integral, meaning the sum is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your argument can be shortened. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality), for any $n\geq 4$
$$ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{n}-2 $$
(i.e. the trapezoid method produces an approximation of the integral which is greater than the actual value) and by rearranging
$$ H_{n}^{(1/2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>2\sqrt{n}-\frac{3}{2} $$
where the RHS is clearly unbounded as $n\to +\infty$.